# If $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=l$, prove $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_1+...+a_n}{n}=l$.

Tags: real-analysis

This question is from Spivak's Calculus 22-16:

[image]

I'm interested in using 13-40 to solve it, but I'm not sure how to fit it.  I tried converting the LHS into something like a Rienmann integral but can't seem to get it just right.  Can anyone use 13-40 as shown below:

[image]

Note: Alternative approach is welcome but I primarily want to use 13-40.  I've seen the official solutions book answer as well.

Comment: My question specifically asks to use the continuous version of the problem as stated in question 40.

Answer (score 1):

Just define $f(t)$ by $f(t)=a_k$ for $k-1<t\le k$. Then
$$\frac1n\int_0^n f(t)\,dt=\frac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}n$$
etc.

ADDED IN EDIT

If you insist on a continuous $f$, again take $f(k)=a_k$
and interpolate linearly on each interval $[k-1,k]$.

Comment: I think the problem is that 13-40 specifically mentions that $f$ is continuous, while your function is certainly not

Comment: Sorry can you explain why that equation is true in the first place?

Comment: If you interpolate linearly I don't see how the integral on the LHS equals $a_1+...+a_n$.